# How can I update document firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I update document with adding all registered users id as a field of updating document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please don't ask easier to find solution questions, which are have answered. When you wanna ask a question here, first please search your question on google, and if you can't find anything about that, then you can ask here.

**And that is code, you can update your date like this:**

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(yourDocumentPath).update({
  //Write just value which you need to update, like a:
  'username': 'This is my new Username',
});
```

Or like this:

```dart
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> updateUser() {
  return users
    .doc('ABC123')
    .update({'company': 'Stokes and Sons'})
    .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
}
```

You can get more about [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage) and [How to update](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#updating-documents) data in cloud firestore. *just search on google*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#updating-documents).